# Uninstall Grunt Globally

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I have installed grunt globally with the following command:

```
sudo npm install grunt -g
```

I read that it's not good practice to install it globally. How do I go about uninstalling it globally?

Looking for some light,

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
sudo npm uninstall grunt -g
```